# Get-Date formatting/culture

Tags: powershell, datetime, powershell-2.0

How do I specify what part of my input string is the date and month?

If the input is `01/10/2017`, this can be read as **1st Oct 2017** and **10th Jan 2017**. Both are correct.

I want to be explicit that `01` is date and `10` is month, so that irrespective of locale and time format I can get a consistent result.

Sample code:

```
get-date  -Date '01/10/2017'
```

The output is:

```
Tuesday, January 10, 2017 12:00:00 AM
```

The desired output is:

```
Sunday, October 01, 2017 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Is this really related only to [tag:PowerShell-v2.0]?

Comment: Read the documentation or run `Get-Help Get-Date` in PowerShell console. You should read the documentation on MSDN that covers [`Get-Date` PowerShell cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) and provides all the necessary examples. Take a closer look at [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date#parameters) section.

Comment: While the issue may apply to all versions of PowerShell, specific solutions may not, so specifying the v2.0 tag indicates that the user is interested in solutions that will work for that version of PowerShell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a solution for you. It requires that the culture as one of the arguments.

```
([datetime]::ParseExact($date,"dd/MM/yyyy",[Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-GB')))
```

A culture does not have to be specified. However, the argument for it does, otherwise you will get an error:

> Cannot find an overload for "ParseExact" and the argument count: "2".

`[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` or `$null` can be used as the third argument:

```
$date = "01/10/2017"
[datetime]::ParseExact($date, "dd/MM/yyyy", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
[datetime]::ParseExact($date, "dd/MM/yyyy", $null)
```

**Output in all three cases**

```
01 October 2017 00:00:00
```

Comment: Good one. Better is `[datetime]::ParseExact("01/10/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)` (no need to create a new specific culture each time) or `[datetime]::ParseExact("01/10/2017", "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", $null)` (once you escape the slash characters with single quotes you do not really care what culture is used during parsing).

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen - Thanks, didn't know those were options. As ideally I wanted to call ParseExact without specifying a 3rd argument. AFC now, will confirm and update answer when I can

Comment: Note the following: (A) The [documentation for `ParseExact` says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx): "If `provider` is __null__, the `CultureInfo` object that corresponds to the current culture is used." (B) If we are on PowerShell 2.0 (old!), the __type accelerator__ `[cultureinfo]` that I used in my first comment is not present, so we have to say `[Globalization.CultureInfo]` in that case, if we decide to give a culture explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Get-Date(Get-Date -Date $date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Comment: Yes Sure @Bittu,Basically you force the date to the format that it requires,and then again feed it to "Get-date  -Date ",So it converts it as it is supposed to.To convert date to a specified date we provide the format (dd-date,MM-months,Years) on (01/10/2017) so after this Your variable is automatically converted into (10/01/2017),And By default your work will be done by Get-Date itself

Comment: This solution is wrong. And what will happen when `$date` is `'20/10/2017'`? It will fail (assuming the current culture prefers `MM/dd/yyyy` like e.g. the English (United States) culture).

Comment: @ChetanKulkarni Thanks for explaining but it does not work for all dates in different cultures. Tried on `en-in` and `en-us`.

Comment: This solution was considering the date format where you explicitly wanted to define that date is dd/MM/YY.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce the culture for single commands (or command blocks). This should help avoiding that date chaos.

```
PS C:\> [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = "en-US" ; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = "en-US"; get-date -Date '01/10/2017'
Tuesday, January 10, 2017 12:00:00 AM

PS C:\> [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = "en-GB" ; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = "en-GB"; get-date -Date '01/10/2017'
01 October 2017 00:00:00
```